# how to get row number in dataframe and store as Id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, primary-key

I wanna get the **row number** of the dataframe and **store it in a new column called `Id`.** Please advise me on how to code it.

Current dataframe:

[image: Current dataframe]

expected outcome with new Id column:

[image: expected dataframe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first column is `index` use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html), if necessary subtract `1`:

```
df.insert(0, 'Id', df.index - 1)
```

If you need count column for general solution with any index values:

```
df.insert(0, 'Id', np.arange(len(df)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[34, 23,37,38],'b':[1,2,3,4]})
df. set_index(a, inplace=True) 

Id = list(df. index) 
df['Id'] = id
```

Answer (score 0):

First, reset an index, it will add as a new column with name index. Then rename the column to the desired name

```
import pandas as pd 
df = (df.reset_index()
      .rename(columns= {'index':'ID'}
     )
```